# Panadas - Check if any value from column A matches to any value in column B

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a Dataframe with userID, IP, Location, IPtoCheck

```
|UserID   IP       Location  IPtoCheck
|Dave     1.1.1.1  ON        2.2.2.2
|Bob      1.2.3.4  ON        1.1.1.1
|Ryan     2.3.4.5  ON        1.3.4.5
```

My goal is to create a new column named IsMatch with a True/False. Take the first value in IPtoCheck and see if it is contained anywhere in column IP and set the boolean value of IsMatch accordingly. Then move onto the next value in IPtoCheck and so on. The end result would look like.

```
|UserID   IP       Location  IPtoCheck  IsMatch
|Dave     1.1.1.1  ON        2.2.2.2    False
|Bob      1.2.3.4  ON        1.1.1.1    True
|Ryan     2.3.4.5  ON        1.3.4.5    False
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `isin`:

```
df["IsMatch"] = df["IPtoCheck"].isin(df["IP"])

>>> df
  UserID       IP Location IPtoCheck  IsMatch
0   Dave  1.1.1.1       ON   2.2.2.2    False
1    Bob  1.2.3.4       ON   1.1.1.1     True
2   Ryan  2.3.4.5       ON   1.3.4.5    False
```